# Local Notification Plugin not working in Ionic App

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to push out some basic notification in my Ionic app. I have followed the official ionic documentation for push notification [Local Notifications](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications).

when i run the app on an actual device, nothing happens, no push notifications are showing up. What could possibly go wrong? if not this, then is there any other plugin for push notification for ionic?

Comment: post the code you have tried so that we can help you

Comment: I have copied the code which is on their official documentation (i have added the link in my question). Still, it is not showing any notifications.

Comment: @Sivaramakrishnan Can you help me with this?

Comment: Is there any errors while you are running the app

Comment: Fixed.  I have posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, instead of Ionic V4 documents, i referred the V3 documents and got it working. This might help some people in future.